# Xbox game update stuck at 100%

Tags: xbox-one, destiny

I left it to update overnight. When I checked it in the morning it said 100%, so I left it for about an hour, but it still says it's at 100%.

What do I do?

Comment: Close the game then relaunch it

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with a hard reset to the console. You do this with a long press of the on/off sensor button on front of the Xbox, or you just keep your finger firmly pressed on it until Xbox powers off. It will take around 10 seconds. It basically clears the cache from the memory.